# Extracting Data from Table Row to assign to inputs

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a site and i want to be able to edit individual rows of data that are populated withing a HTML table from a mysql database. Now i know how to do the PHP to make the updates to the database, but what i am having trouble with is populating my modal fields with the selected rows data.

My HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-custom">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Field1</th>
                <th>Field2</th>
                <th>Field3</th>
                <th>Field4</th>
                <th>Field5</th>
                <th>Field6</th>
                <th>Field7</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#editRecord" id="edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteRecord" id="delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#editRecord" id="edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteRecord" id="delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editRecord">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="custom-header modal-header ">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" id="editRecordId" name="editRecordId" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="field2">field2</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field2" name="field2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="field3">field3</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field3" name="field3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="field5">Computer Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field5" name="field5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="field7" name="field7">
                                <option value="1">Active</option>
                                <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data1 = parent.find('td').eq(0).html();
        var data2 = parent.find('td').eq(1).html();
        var data3 = parent.find('td').eq(2).html();
        var data5 = parent.find('td').eq(4).html();
        var data7 = parent.find('td').eq(6).html();

        $('#editRecordId').val(data1);
        $('#field2').val(data2);
        $('#field3').val(data3);
        $('#field5').val(data5);
        $('#field7').val(data7);
    });
});
```

The problem that I am having is that when the Edit button is clicked for any row I am only getting the information from the first row populating. Its populating fine, but I don't get the data from the row i am in, only the first one. So for the purpose of editing each row this doesnt work, and i cant figure out why.

Also i am using bootstrap for the framework and everything else is OOP PHP with a table class generating the table for me.

Comment: `#edit` is an **ID**, and should only exist once on a page.  Since you have more than one edit button, you need to change to using a class such as `.edit`.

Comment: And once you have done what @cale_b has told you then modify your jQuery selector to `$('.edit')`

Comment: That did it. Stupid of me to make it a id and not a class. Thanks a ton.